# How many directed multigraphs with n vertices and edges up to isomorphisms

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many graphs (not isomorphic to each other) with the same number of edges as vertices (sometimes called autographs). I'm interested in autographs where the edges are directed, and there may be 0 or more edges between any ordered pair of vertices.

Ideally, I'd like a formula to calculate the number of such graphs for a given number of vertices/edges n.

I have absolutely no idea how to find an algebraic formula for this, so I wrote some code to generate all the possible graphs and then to filter out the isomorphisms.

This gives the first few terms in the series:
(EDIT: n = 4 is incorrect)

```
# of autographs  1 1 6 31 1201
               n 0 1 2 3  4
```

Of course it's possible that there is a mistake in my code, so these numbers could be wrong.

I did not find an entry for this sequence in the [integer sequences page](https://oeis.org/)

---

Update: As shared by pasthec it looks like the sequence is included here: https://oeis.org/A138107

1, 1, 6 ,31, 198, 1270, 8838,  63419

See Table 79 on page 32 of [Statistics on Small Graphs by
Richard J. Mathar](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.09000.pdf)

Comment: I assume you also allow loops, or else there would not be an autograph with $1$ vertex.

Comment: I think there is a mistake with your code, as I got 1,6,31,198, which agrees with the diagonal terms of https://oeis.org/A138107 (the next are 1270, 8838, 63419). Given both this sequence and https://oeis.org/A136564 don't seem to have good formulas for computing the diagonal terms, I don't think one is known.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, loops too. I thought that was included when I wrote that there can be 0 or more edges between a pair of vertices. If v is a vertex, then a loop is an edge for the ordered pair (v, v). I could have been more explicate about this.

Comment: @pasthec Thank you, A138107 indeed looks like the sequence I need! It will help me debug my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: The software at [OEIS A138107](https://oeis.org/A138107) is sufficient to answer this post.

Comment: I kinda expected you to answer this, thanks for that! If I understand correctly, you compute information that gives all counts of multigraphs with n vertices and k edges along the way, do you think there is hope for some recursive relations which would use the fact we only care about the diagonal (this could give simpler to compute exact formula and maybe better algorithmic complexity)?